# Label propagation scoring with grid search and cross-fold validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to perform a grid search using scikit-learn and GridSearchCV. For cross-fold validation I'm splitting my data using StratifiedShuffleSplit.

If I use an approach like Random Forest, all works well. However with Label Propagation or Label spreading, I run into an issue with scoring. This is due to the fact that some of the labels in my training data need to be converted to the unlabelled class (-1).

Let's say my training data consists of 6 samples with labels 0 or 1.

```
labels = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

I pretend some of those are unlabelled during training by converting them to -1

```
labels_w_some_unlabelled = [0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1]
```

Using StratifiedShuffleSplit, let's say my data is split in the first fold to the following indices:

```
train_indices = [0, 1, 3]
test_indices = [2, 4, 5]

test_labels = [-1, 1, -1]
```

When I run the grid search and my data gets scored, the ground truth for labels contains the unlabelled classes

```
cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit()
grid_search = GridSearchCV(
   estimator='LabelPropagation',
   cv=cv,
   ...
)
grid_search.fit(training_data, test_labels)
```

Any of the test labels with the unlabelled class cannot get a correct prediction, because their 'ground truth' for the scoring function will be the -1/unlabelled class.

I want to create a custom scoring function and pass it to `GridSearchCV`, but it doesn't seem that the indices used in each fold get passed to this function, so I can't get the correct labels for anything in the test set.

```
def custom_scoring_function(estimator, X, y):
   '''
   X has 3 samples for the test data. y is the ground truth,
   but contains -1 for unlabelled data and isn't the ground truth I want.
   '''
   groud_truth = [] # extract correct labels using indices of test data somehow 
   y_pred = estimator.predict(X)
   return accuracy_score(ground_truth, y_pred)

cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit()
grid_search = GridSearchCV(
   estimator='LabelPropagation',
   cv=cv,
   scoring=custom_scoring_function
   ...
)
grid_search.fit(training_data, test_labels)
```

I could just build my own grid search function but thought there might be another way.